# Sending Long to Shared Preferences - Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, long-integer

I've developed a dialog box that prompts a user to enter his/her phone number when the app first runs but I'm having trouble adding it to the shared preferences. I have the SP set up and working correctly from another view (to add/edit info) and I was able to commit a user id. The problem is that I'm using a Long for the phone number instead of a string, so I keep getting errors and can't seem to figure out what I need to do. I think the Editable may also be an issue. I've tried changing getText() to getLong() but that doesn't seem to work and I can't convert it to a string because the phone number is recognized as a Long in my SP. How can I commit the Long to the shared preferences? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    if(phone == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Please Enter Your Phone Number");
        alert.setMessage("You must enter your phone number in order to use this application");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        Editable value = input.getText();

        Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putLong("PHONE", value); //wants me to change putLong to putString
        editor.commit();
         }
        });
        alert.show();     
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with this practice. You may end up getting phones numbers with "+" and/or "-" and then all Hell breaks loose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex, you could do the following to put a Long into the SP:

```
String value = input.getText().toString();

Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putLong("PHONE", Long.valueOf(value));
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I think this is close, but the app crashes and I get the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

Comment: May I ask as to exact reason you are storing the phone number as a long? Personally, I would only store a phone number as either a String or an Integer, but not a Long.

Comment: I feel like there was a reason but I can't remember. I'll try to switch it to a string. I am storing this in a database, could I store a phone number as VARCHAR? I feel like I was unable to or something.

Comment: A VARCHAR will be fine. Please don't change everything at your end before thinking of the reason again. I would hate to put you in a tangle at your end! One other piece of advice, if your not doing already, use the following XML attribute on your EditText view: android:inputType="phone". This will limit the characters the user can put into the EditText view and thus save you some headaches.

Comment: I changed it to a string and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english

you doesn't convert String value into Long

use `parseLong(String s, int radix)` method like this: `parseLong(value, 10)`

Comment: Could you expand on this? I was trying it before with no luck, but I didn't have a second argument. What is that number for anyway?

Comment: second argument is a base of numeral system which you want use

Answer (score 0):

change

Editable value = input.getText();

to

```
String value = input.getText().toString();
```

This will give you the String value of the Textbox.

Now to store.

If and only if you are sure(and you have validated) that the `value` here only contains digits, do:

```
editor.putLong("PHONE", Long.valueOf(value));
```

still i would prefer

```
editor.putString("PHONE",value);
```

and you can retrieve it with string anytime too,and then change it to Long as required...